# Route::controller Unit Test issue Laravel

Tags: unit-testing, routes, laravel, laravel-4

since I modified my routing structure my unit tests are going crazy... Here's my routing:

```
Route::group( ['prefix' => 'api/v1'],function () {
 Route::group( array('before' => 'appauth'), function () {
 Route::get('ciao',function () {
   return Response::json(Success::instance(array()));
 });
Route::controller('appuserslogin','AppUsersLoginController');
etc.....
});
```

Now, if I run my tests, I get this error: 
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Router::anything()` and the line the error is referring to is the line with Route::controller etc....

If I removed the line Route::controller etc.. everything is OK.

If I try to "test" the "appuserslogin" URL it in the browser (i.e. going to `http://websiteurl/api/v1/appuserslogin/login?appKey=APPK&username=USERNAME&password=PASS`) it works. So it's not a routing problem. 
Please don't mind the query parameters since they will be removed afterwards..

Do you have any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me recently, but it wasn't the route actually causing the issue.  The issue was that I had accidentally named a test with a name identical to a controller, instead of appending "Test" to the end of the class name.  (Example: I had "LandingController" for the test name instead of "LandingControllerTest".)

Noticed the class name, fixed it, and problem solved.